# Inserting a string into my Html code from Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, web-deployment

I am a new programmer and I am trying to load a JSON as a string into my HTML code so that I can make a table that changes with each request that is made. My python code loads the HTML by doing the following:

```
        def render_POST(self, request):
            file = open(os.path.join(html, 'home_screen.html'),'r')
            filedata = file.read()
            return filedata % (JSON as a String,)
```

The part of my HTML code that I am trying to add this json to is:

```
    <div id="dynamicTable" ng-app="" ng-init=names= %s  >
            <table border="24px", bordercolor="blue" >
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                    <td> <a href = "{{ x.link }}  "> {{ x.Name }}</td>
                    <td> <a href = "{{ x.link }}  "> {{ x.company }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

The %s is where I am trying to insert the JSON. Each row of the JSON has a Name, company, and link. I have gotten several type errors and I haven't been able to get the JSON into the HTML table. Is this the proper way to do it? If not, is there another way to get my JSON to display in the HTML. I have heard that putting the JSON into the body of the request may make things easier but I don't know exactly how to do that. My JSON is not in a file, but in the python code itself. I can NOT pass the JSON to the HTML code through putting into a file.

If you need to see more of my code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
dict_with_the_key_values = {"key0":"whatever", "key1":"tututu"}

asd = "some text {key0} lorem ipsum {key1}".format(**dict_with_the_key_values)

print(asd) # "some text whatever lorem ipsum tututu"
```